# Downloading a photo from twitpic url

Tags: php, ruby, parsing

Is there any way of downloading an image from Twitpic URL? Let's say I want to get next photo http://twitpic.com/49275c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The corresponding link for an image with ID of `49275c` is given by

http://twitpic.com/show/full/49275c for a full sized image.

Replace 'full' with 'thumb' or 'mini' for different sizes.

```
http://twitpic.com/show/[size]/[image-id]
```

You should really have a look at the API and tinker: 
http://dev.twitpic.com/

Answer (score 1):

As @Gordon has pointed out in a comment, **twitpic seems to have an API** -- which you should use, for this kind of thing.

See : **http://dev.twitpic.com/**

---

*Now, here's the old answer -- fun, but not really a good idea, considering there is an API :*

The URL you have is not the URL of the image itself : it's the URL of an HTML page, in which the image is displayed, in an `<img>` tag.

So, you need to act in two steps :

- First, load that page, and extract the URL of the `<img>` tag.

  - This can probably be done using [**`DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)
- Then, when you have the image's URL, you can download it

  - Using [**`file_get_contents`**](http://fr.php.net/file_get_contents),
  - Or [**curl**](http://fr.php.net/curl).

And here's an example of code that does that :

```
$twitpic_url = 'http://twitpic.com/49275c';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
if (@$dom->loadHTMLFile($twitpic_url)) {
    // HTML loaded successfully
    // => You need to find the right <img> tag
    // Looking at the HTML, you'll see it has id="photo-display"
    $img_tag = $dom->getElementById('photo-display');
    
    $src = $img_tag->getAttribute('src');
    
    // Just to be sure, let's display the image's URL
    var_dump($src);
    
    // Now, you have to download the image which URL is $src
    $img_content = file_get_contents($src);
    
    // ANd do whatever you want with that binary image content
    // like save if to a file :
    file_put_contents('/tmp/my-image.jpg', $img_content);
}
```

*Note : you have to add some checks here and there -- like check if the photo-display element exists, for instance.*

Comment: Yeah, but TwitPic has an API which can do that in much less code and more reliably.

Comment: Ergh ; should have checked if there was an API... using it would indeed be a much better idea ^^ *(I'll edit my answer to point that out)*

Comment: There [already is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290145/how-to-download-photo-from-twitpic/5290189#5290189) pointing that out though ;)

Comment: Hell :-( That's been posted while I was editing my answer to provide an example ^^ Well, that other answer has been accepted, which was the right thing to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly from the Twitter API, using the [entities parameter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities).